# How can I create a custom JSON string/structure?

Tags: json, ruby, fastlane

I am trying to get a custom JSON structure (example below) output in order for it to be parsed by an engine.

```
{"index":{"projectName":"nativeCart","buildID":1467}}
{"@timestamp":"2015-05-18T09:03:25.877Z","executedTests":230,"testFailures":0,"currentCoverage":56,"lintViolations":60,"lintWarnings":337,"lintErrors":0,"buildStatus":"Success"}
```

I have tried using the default json structure

```
require 'json'

test = {
  'projectName' => 'nativeCart',
  'buildID' => 1467
}
```

but it won't be giving me the index part of the json. So, how can I create these jsons in ruby?

Comment: Add the `index` to your own hash. `{'index' => {'projectName' => '...', 'buildID' => '...'}}`

Answer (score 0):

You can transform any Hash\Array to json using .to_json method.
In your case you are showing 2 separate hashes.
So you may combine them

```
require 'json'
test = { index: { projectName: 'nativeCart', buildID: 1467 },
         '@timestamp' => '2015-05-18T09:03:25.877Z', 
         executedTests: 230, testFailures: 0, currentCoverage: 56,
         lintViolations: 60, lintWarnings: 337, lintErrors: 0,
         buildStatus: 'Success' }
test.to_json
```